# QT and C++: can't call function outside main() function

Tags: c++, qt, class, function

I would like to know how to call the function **Do_Download()** from the **SocketTest** class outisde the **main()** function.
The first **cTest.Do_Download()** does work, but when I call the **test()** function, the **csTest.Do_Download()** does not work.

So it looks like I can only acces **SocketTest** from inside the **main()** function, and not from any other function.

Does somebody know how this can be solved?
Thanks!

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    SocketTest cTest;
        cTest.Do_Download();

    return a.exec();
}


void test()
{
    qDebug() << "test main functie";

    SocketTest csTest;
        csTest.Do_Download();
}
```

SocketTest.h:

```
#ifndef SOCKETTEST_H
#define SOCKETTEST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QHttp>
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>

class SocketTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SocketTest(QObject *parent = 0);


   void Do_Download();
signals:

public slots:

    void stateChanged ( int state );
    void responseHeaderReceived ( const QHttpResponseHeader & resp );
    void requestFinished ( int id, bool error );

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;
    QHttp *http;
    QHttp *http2;

};

#endif // SOCKETTEST_H
```

Comment: I don't see you are calling `test` function at all from main ?

Comment: When do you call `test()`? The event loop might need to be running. On an unrelated note, `QHttp` is deprecated. You should use `QNetworkAccessManager` instead if possible.

Comment: I call test() in mainwindow.cpp. The application outputs the debug message, so I'm sure the test() function is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `DoDownload` function is doing anything asynchronously (likely, when dealing with the Qt networking classes), the `SocketTest` you are creating in `test()` is being destroyed before it can act on any return value.

It works in `main()` because the event loop starts and the `SocketTest` instance hangs around.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It makes sense to me. Do you know how to prevent test() from being destroyed to quick? Then I can test it and see if it works.

Comment: You would create a `SocketTest` *pointer*. Then you have to worry about deleting it when it is done. If `test` is part of a class, you could make the pointer a member of the class and delete it in the destructor of the class. Otherwise, you might be able to do it in something like your `requestFinished` slot.